# How to run google CLI commands in a linux shell script?

Tags: shell, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm trying to create a cronjob in my VM server that run a shell script that upload the apache log to a bigquery table and the script have this assertments:

```
#!/bin/bash

bq load --project_id=myproject --field_delimiter=" " mylogs.mylogsfont /var/log/apache2/access.log /var/log/apache2/schema_access.txt

rm /var/log/apache2/access.log

/etc/init.dapache2 restart
```

but the bq load command do not run.

Is there a way to run this command in a shell script?

I've looked thru the web and I found the boto files and gcsfuse but both talks about jobs with the storage and have no metntions to bigquery jobs

Comment: Try to set the full path of bq binaries. bq could not be in the path of the current cronjob runtime and therefore the command is not found. It's a common issue with bash script ;)

Comment: it worked!!! in my case the path was /snap/bin/bq , with the arguments, it runs smoothly!!! Thank you!!!!

Comment: Keep it in mind!! It will be the same for startup script, shut down script, and anything that you don't launch with your currently connected user!